# html5 Video not playing in iPad

Tags: javascript, ipad, html, video-streaming

I have a video tag, which working fine in Safari, Chrome but not on iPad/iPhone. Whats I am doing wrong.

```
<a onclick="showVideoPlayer('http://www.mywebsite.com/videos/a video file.m4v')" id="video1" href="#">Play video</a>
```

js code

```
function showVideoPlayer(videoSrc, showDownloadLink){
            alert(videoSrc);
            if(!videoSrc)
                return;

            $('div#overlay').show();
            var $videoPlaceHolder = $('div#video-placeholder');
            $videoPlaceHolder.show();

            var $video = $videoPlaceHolder.find('video');

            var winWidth = $(window).width() - 80;
            var winHeight = $(window).height() - 120;

            $video.attr('src', videoSrc);
            $video.attr('width', winWidth + 'px');
            $video.attr('height', winHeight + 'px');
            $videoPlaceHolder.append($video);
            if(showDownloadLink){
                $('#video-placeholder .down').show();
            }

        }
```

Comment: Please can you give the markup of #video-placeholder?

Answer (score 0):

iOS is notorious for being extra-fussy about playing back videos. Here's a few things to check for:

1. Video encoded using H.264 Baseline Profile (other profiles are not guaranteed to play under iOS)
2. Video file being served with an appropriate content-type header (`binary/octet-stream` will not work on iOS)
3. If you end up using `<source type="foo" src="bar" />` tags within your `<video />`, ensure that the value of the `type` attribute matches exactly the `content-type` header supplied by the server - this is case-sensitive.
4. The server delivering the video file must support byte range requests - iOS Safari's developer console should show complaints along these lines if this is the problem.

Those are the most common errors I've come across (I work at an online video platform) - hopefully, your problem will be as simple as finding out which requirement you're missing.